# How to retrieve mutiple image which are stored in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The code(function) used by me to store an image is:

```
function X = ReadImgs(Folder,ImgType)
    Imgs = dir([Folder '/' ImgType]);
    NumImgs = size(Imgs,1);
    image = double(imread([Folder '/' Imgs(1).name]));
    X = zeros([NumImgs size(image)]);
    for i=1:NumImgs,
      image = double(imread([Folder '/' Imgs(i).name]));
      if (size(image,3) == 1)
        X(i,:,:) = image;
      else
        X(i,:,:,:) = image;
    end
end
```

---

```
ImageData = ReadImgs('sample images','*.jpg');
```

I am unable to retrieve one image at a time.
Matlab experts plz help..

Comment: Did all image have the same size ?

Comment: Dimensions are same:1280x720,Size are in the range:126KB to 160KB. I am trying to store the images and then retrieve them one by one,so that I can compare the two images.

Comment: check `Imgs` structure... I suspect it doesn't have number of entries equal to number of images.

Comment: i have checked Imgs has all the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to load the images in a cell, like that:

```
for i=1:NumImgs;
   Stack{i} = double(imread([Folder '/' Imgs(i).name]));
end
```

This is robust to image dimensions and type (RGB, grayscale, etc.)

You can then access any image of that cell by using the index. Try: `imshow(Stack{1})` or if you want to compare 2 of them: `imshowpair(Stack{1}, Stack{2})` etc.

Comment: Image has been saved, but not able to retrieve it.

Comment: After storing an image how can I get an image(all images)

Comment: I have to store 1(all) image at a time and again I have to 1(all) image at a time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'store'? Do you mean load them in your matlab workspace (that is what I suspect form your initial code)

Comment: yes I have to first save(load) in matlab, second getting that saved images

Comment: Your problem is mysterious to me… You have all the images in a cell, just use what I wrote in my comment above to access any individual image of the cell.